# How to make pandas's Series only plot the data in index?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, series

**EDIT** The missed dates 20140103 and 20140104 is expected, I don't want them to be patched auto.
And I don't want to use `xs = pd.Series(data=range(len(ts)), index=pd.to_datetime(ts))` instead of `xs = pd.Series(data=range(len(ts)), index=pd.to_datetime(ts))` since I want to use some operation as

```
xs = pd.Series(data=range(len(ts)), index=pd.to_datetime(ts))

xs['2014']
Out[24]: 
2014-01-01    0
2014-01-02    1
2014-01-05    2
2014-01-06    3
2014-01-07    4
dtype: int64
```

which doesn't work for:

```
In [26]: xs = pd.Series(data=range(len(ts)), index=ts)

In [27]: xs['2014']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError: '2014'
```

---

For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: ts = ['20140101', '20140102', '20140105', '20140106', '20140107']

In [3]: xs = pd.Series(data=range(len(ts)), index=pd.to_datetime(ts))

In [4]: xs.plot()
```

Will plot this image, which add the extra data on 20140103, 20140104.
[image]

While I want to got a image like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(xs.values)
```

[image]

Comment: Because there are some missing points, while plotting matplotlib interpolates the data points for in between points. xs.values gives a list, and matplotlib is plotting the values of list versus list index, which apparently are the same [0,1,2,3,4]. Thats why you are getting straight line.

Comment: I figured it out , w8 for 10 min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to euri10 for use_index = False

```
ts = ['20140101', '20140102', '20140105', '20140106', '20140107']
xs = pd.Series(data=range(len(ts)), index=pd.to_datetime(ts))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xs.plot(use_index=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(pd.to_datetime(ts))
ax.set_xticks(range(len(ts)))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I don't want to use `Series(data=range(len(ts)), index=ts)`.

Comment: @Yes. Actually your new approach is based on matplotlib rather than  pandas. your `xs.plot(use_index=False)` can be replace by `ax.plot(xs.values)`. I wonder if there is a simple solution only need to change some parameter of pandas.

Comment: xs.plot(use_index=False is based on pandas while ax.plot(xs.values) is explicit matplotlib, and even pandas uses matplotlib for plotting.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't test it but you may want to use use_index=False and/or xticks

Answer (score 1):

Since you converted the dates to datetime, pandas is plotting the dates themselves on the x-axis. Since there are days that aren't included in the Series, pandas will leave the appropriate spaces on the x-axis where those points are. If, for some reason, you don't want this (for instance, if you are counting business days and the missing points are weekends), I think the solution that makes it most clear is to make the index not a date but a number (Day 1, Day 2, etc.). To my knowledge, pandas won't allow you to distort the axes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
ts = ['20140101', '20140102', '20140105', '20140106', '20140107']

xs = pd.Series(data=range(len(ts)), index=pd.to_datetime(ts))
print xs


#output
2014-01-01    0
2014-01-02    1
2014-01-05    2
2014-01-06    3
2014-01-07    4
```

You are missing 2 dates.